# Bootstrap Image Link not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have a logo image in my header and I have the standard code in there, the browser source code even shows it, but the link isn't going anywhere. Please see below:

```
<a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive hidden-xs" src="img/sitewide-images/logo.png" width="106" height="106" alt=""/></a>
```

Here is a link to it live on a testing server: http://wsieworksstaging.com/ptmw/index.html

Comment: why should it? You're on `index.html`, and linking to `index.html`. so you're just clicking onwards to the exact same page.

Comment: You should run that code through a validator while you're at it. Seems to have a few dozen issues.

Comment: I ran it through Dreamweaver CC's W3C validator and it validated, says no errors or warnings found [HTML5].

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri

Comment: Here is another page with the same thing that passed with the note below:

http://www.wsieworksstaging.com/ptmw/ptm-w-products/epoxy-products/epoxy-tooling-materials/room-temperature/rt-surface-coats.html

The uploaded document "rt-surface-coats.html" was successfully checked as HTML5. This means that the resource in question identified itself as "HTML5" and that we successfully performed a formal validation of it. The parser implementations we used for this check are based on validator.nu (HTML5).

Comment: I see your html code. why you use 2 <a> tags with the same href and image? Try to remove one of them and check out the result

Comment: I have one of them hiding at the xs browser size and the other hiding all the time. I did this so that I could center the logo at mobile size...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bootstrap** should be `container` > `row` > `column`

You didn't place those columns within a row, so the row below isn't clearing and is overlaying it. Try this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row"> <!-- wrap with a row to force the content below to clear  -->

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">..</div>

        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">..</div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inner" role="navigation"> .. </nav>

    </div>

</div>
```

---

**[From The Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)**

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
>   Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.

Answer (score 3):

Because your div with the class row is sitting on top of it and blocking any clicks. Add `clear:left` to have it get out of the way, and the link will become clickable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, should I use clear:left on the image or the div with a class of row?

Comment: The div with the class of row.

Comment: However it will change the effective `height` of `header`.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesnt seem to be working, I have updated the server if you would be able to look and see if I did it wrong...

Comment: Wrap in a row like I demonstrated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25558329/1342440

Comment: ok I will click that for you, I have never used this site before so I apologize if it takes me a min to get used to, but thank you Brian, your answer did work

Answer (score 0):

You can also try giving that anchor an absolute `position` and a `z-index` value.

```
a[href="index.html"] {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```